# Call Different URL Form JavaScript on Different Radio button selected

Tags: javascript, php, html

is there a way where i can send data to different php urls from java script based on radio button selected.

Example:

```
Html
```

html radio button is selected 
then call only **html.php** from JavaScript

and

```
CSS
```

css radiobutton is selected

then call only **CSS.php**

Html.

```
<div>Choose option:</div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options" value="css" /> CSS 
<input type="radio" name="user_options" value="jquery" /> jQuery 
<input type="radio" name="user_options" value="html" /> HTML
<input type="radio" name="user_options" value="php" /> PHP
```

Script to php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var datahtml = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
            if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == "0") {
                alert("Select any value");
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "html.php",
                    data: "htmldata=" + htmldata,
                    success: function () {
                        $("#msg").addClass('bg');

                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well you can use an array/map to store which url you should reach according to the radio you've clicked on. Then, when you click on a radio button, you can retrieve which url you should call and setting it as the "url" value in the ajax call

Comment: Can u share the example for the above.?

Comment: Shouldn't this `data: "htmldata=" + htmldata,` be this `data: "htmldata=" + datahtml,`

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's an idea actually but I'm not saying this is perfect.

What you can do is, for each, button, storing what url you should reach by clicking on it, e.g :

```
<input type="radio" name="user_options" data-url="http://example.org/css" value="css" /> CSS 
<input type="radio" name="user_options" data-url="http://example.org/jquery" value="jquery" /> jQuery 
<input type="radio" name="user_options" data-url="http://example.org/html" value="html" /> HTML
<input type="radio" name="user_options" data-url="http://example.org/php" value="php" /> PHP
```

As you can see, we added some custom properties to each button to store their destination. Then, into the click event handler, right after `dataHtml`, you can do :

```
var remoteUrl=$('input[type="radio"]:checked').data("url");
```

and then replacing

```
url: "html.php",
```

by

```
url: remoteUrl,
```

You'll probably need to adapt some names but here is the idea.

hope it will help you

Comment: but tat shuld b done only when button is clicked not on radio button click

Comment: isn't it the expected behavior actually ? This code is encountered after the $("#submit").click(function(){

Answer (score 0):

You can make what goes into `url` a variable, with an object literal map to fill in the value. You just have to make sure that you're accounting for all possible scenarios or provide a default url. Otherwise, the url will be undefined. Example below (note: I haven't tested it, but this should give you the general idea).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){

    // this is your object map. just make sure that you account 
    //for all of the values, otherwise you'll throw an error. 
    var urls = {
      'css': 'css.php', 
      'html': 'html.php'
    };

    var datahtml = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();

    if($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == "0") {
      alert("Select any value");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urls[datahtml], //this is your variable that pulls from the urls object
        data: "htmldata="+htmldata,
        success: function() {
           $("#msg").addClass('bg');
        }
      });
     }
    return false;
  });
});
```